# ¿Cómo dar formato a un XML alimentado de una consulta a BD?

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Estoy tratando de crear un XML haciendo una consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT idEmpleado, NombreEmpleado FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE idEmpleado = " + idEmp, cn);
                SqlCommand cmd = adapter.SelectCommand;
                adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            ds.WriteXml(new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter));
            output = stringWriter.ToString();
            vDocumento.LoadXml(output);
            cn.Close();
```

Lo que me retorna es lo siguiente:

`<Table1>
   <idEmpleado>1</idEmpleado>
   <NombreEmpleado >Alex</NombreEmpleado >
</Table1>`

Pero quiero que en lugar de `<Table1>` quiero que salga "Empleado" y a su vez añadirle un par de lineas al sql aparte de las generadas.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando SQL Server puedes utilizar la cláusula "For xml" de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT idEmpleado, NombreEmpleado 
FROM EMPLEADOS 
WHERE idEmpleado = 2
for xml auto()
```

Cualquier duda adicional consulta
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-auto-mode-with-for-xml?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, acabo de editar la pregunta para hacerla un poco más clara. No sé si sabes sobre eso.